# How can i add the FROM address in React-Native mailling?

Tags: javascript, react-native

```
 <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => Communications.email(['emailAddress1', 'emailAddress2'],null,null,'My Subject','My body text')}>
          <View style={styles.holder}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>Send an email</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
```

Hello guys , im trying to use the react native mailling , and i try to find somthing that i can pass the FROM address , but all the librairy that i've tried i allways find the (to,cc,bcc,subject,body) and i need to give the FROM address i d'ont know if it's possible ? im using react-native-communications now but i even tried other librairy like (react-native-email...)

Comment: that's not possible you can't give from address.
Suppose that if you give from mail address then that email address need be logged in to your email app on mobile device and you can't login to any email address.
logically it's not correct and feasible

Comment: that's true , that's logic , Thank you Rahul